# 'pip install --upgrade pip' command not working for macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

I can't upgrade the pip, and install packages.

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt'`

`You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Comment: Have you tried `sudo` ?

Comment: I just tried, and the upgrade works! But when I tried installing a python library the OSError appears, does that mean I have to use sudo all the time?

Comment: Yes you have to use `sudo` so why virtualenv recommend. Try to use virtualenv to install package via pip. Then you won't have to use sudo all the time

Comment: Yes, you have probably installed pip as root the first time - so you will always have to use sudo.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! Really helpful.